# What is the difference between perceptrons and weighted McCulloch-Pitts?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

While reading a book on Neural networks by Rojas, I encountered two statements in different places that seemed contradictory to me as I thought perceptrons and weighted McCulloch-Pitts networks are the same. The statements are:

> Since McCulloch–Pitts networks do not use weighted edges the question of whether weighted networks are more general than unweighted ones must be answered. A simple example shows that **both kinds of networks are equivalent.**
>
> A perceptron network is capable of computing any logical function, **since perceptrons are even more powerful than unweighted McCulloch–Pitts elements.**

How do they differ?

Comment: Note that "equivalent" does not mean "same performance" but that they can represent the same solution spaces (although in different ways). The trade-off here is in the complexity weighting brings vs complexity of topology an "equivalent" unweighted network will require.

Comment: Are are you saying that when the author says `more powerful` he is talking about performance?

Comment: Not really, probably more "expressive" or "concise". It takes many more nodes without weight to do the same thing that weighting achieves, so I would expect on standard CPUs for weighting would be more performant. Massively parallel dedicated systems might flip that around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two passages looks like taken out the context a bit. I think, the answer to your question can be found in the same work:

> The ﬁgure shows that positive rational weights can be simulated by simply
>   fanning-out the edges of the network the required number of times. This means
>   that we can either use weighted edges or go for a more complex topology of
>   the network, with many redundant edges.

And later about negative weights:

> As shown above, we can implement any kind of logical function using
>   unweighted networks. What we trade is the simplicity of the building blocks for
>   a more convoluted topology of the network.

So, the answer is: networks with weighted edges are simpler and tend to have more unified structure, they are easy to construct and train in comparison with unweighted networks.

I think, the idea of the author (about the power of perceptrons) is explained in the following paragraph:

> We arrived at the conclusion that McCulloch–Pitts units can be used to
>   build networks capable of computing any logical function and of
>   simulating any ﬁnite automaton [**but**] the network must be
>   completely speciﬁed before it can be used. There are no free
>   parameters which could be adjusted to suit diﬀerent problems. Learning
>   can only be implemented by modifying the connection pattern of the
>   network and the thresholds of the units, but this is necessarily more
>   complex than just adjusting numerical parameters.

This is why perceptrons are more powerful (meaning flexible and unified).

Comment: Well my question was: when the author says perceptrons are more powerful does he mean they solve a wider range of problems than McCulloch–Pitts networks?

Comment: The short answer: NO, meaning they can both solve the same range of problems, but perceptron provides a uniformed approach for solving these problems, whereas unweighted networks require a provisonal (manual, or computerized) analytical phase of structure deduction. This is why perceptron is more powerful. I'm going to add more citation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Stan. What book other than this one do you recommend me for my first course in Neural networks. Something up-to-date?

Comment: There are so many interesting books... I'm not sure if it's suited for the first course, but the bible is Neural Networks: A Comprehensive Foundation by Simon Haykin.